# ajax form submission - skip url processing and go directly to success function?

Tags: ajax, jquery

Haven't come across this before with ajax.  On click of a button I am posting a form with ajax.  In the successful return function I am opening up a modal window in bootstrap 3 with a single parameter attached from the previous form submission.

I am using the modal as a confirmation window to confirm a user deletion.  I am using ajax again then in the modal to do the actual deletion of the user in the db and returning success or fail.

Since all the operations are being processed in the actual modal's ajax (confirm the username exists then perform the delete operations)... is there a way I can skip the initial form processing?  In this example `p_delete_user.php'` really does absolutely nothing other than allow me to return and attach the username parameter to the modal I open.

Can I skip this step somehow and go straight to my success calls with the attached parameter value.  I have no need to check if the param is valid or not in this step as the validation occurs in the ajax of the modal that is opened.

**my ajax:**

```
// delete user account
var deleteAccount = function() {
    $('#delete-user').on('click', function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/spc_admin/process/p_delete_user.php',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType : 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {
            if (response.success) {

                // user account exists so show confirmation modal
                $('#modal-ajax').load('/spc_admin/modals/m_delete_user.php?username='+response.username+'');
                $('#modal-ajax').modal('show');

            } 
            else 
            {
                // show error toast
                toastr.error('An error has occurred. &nbsp;Please contact support.', 'Error');
            }
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Javascript to get the username from the form, and put that directly into the modal:

```
var deleteAccount = function() {
    $('#delete-user').on('click', function () {
        var username = $(this).closest('form').find("input[name=username]").val();
        $('#modal-ajax').load('/spc_admin/modals/m_delete_user.php?username='+encodeURIComponent(username));
        $('#modal-ajax').modal('show');
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm actually reading up on the same thing now as this popped in my head.  At the moment I was looking at how to combine the closest form and input into one call.  Also, what is the proper way to attach that variable then? `'+username+' if that is the variable I store the value?

Comment: I fixed that, I forgot to remove `response.` when I was editing your code.

Comment: Awesome... much simpler than I thought.  Also, realizing I had a dumb moment even posting this question.  Ajax was never needed such as I wanted lol.  Thanks!

Comment: The extra `+''` also wasn't needed. I don't know where people pick up these bad habits. Obviously just copying code without bothering to read it and understand what it does.

Comment: That was me missing that part... copy and paste from another part of my code where it was inline with text on each side.